# Keeping track of created markers using Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm building an application that lets my users create several markers on a map.  I need to keep track of each point they create and be able to search for a given point by an unique ID.  How would I go about doing this?  Is there anything native to the API that would support tracking points being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will depend on why you want to track markers.
The most common approach is to create a markers array and add each marker object to it after creation. Later you can access all the marker data as you require it. Note you can also attach your own properties to the marker as well such as

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
map:map,
position: latLng,
myOwnProperty: "yes you can do that"
})
alert(marker.myOwnProperty)
```

later you would simply search the array of markers for the value of that property

If you want markers to respond to events (each marker doing different thing let's say on click) you would also attach appropriate events and content to each marker and let the MVCObject magic take care of the rest. A good example is here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures

Comment: Thanks for the "myOwnProperty" reference.  I was going to create a wrapper object for it...

Answer (score 1):

Well, on the javascript end of things it sounds like there should not be a problem. When you create a marker, you have a reference to it. So you can easily hold it, map it to this unique string, and recall it when you need it.

Do you mean storing these in a DB? Because then you just need a table with the coords and the unique string.

Perhaps I am missing some details but it seems very doable (I just had to do something very similar)

Comment: No what you are saying is a thought I had.  I was just wondering really if Google's API had a list of these references already for me to use.